# Deploy phpmyadmin to kubernetes issue

Tags: mysql, docker, kubernetes, phpmyadmin

I have the following configuration to deploy phpmyadmin to kubernetes.I have two problems with this:

1. When the pod goes up it doesn't start the apache, I have to run `service apache2 start`
2. when I enter phpmyadmin I find that it has not taken the environment variable PMA_HOST that is pointing to the IP where the database is up and running

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: phpmyadmin
  labels:
    app: phpmyadmin
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: phpmyadmin
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: phpmyadmin
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: phpmyadmin
          image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:5
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
          env:
            - name: PMA_HOST
              value: MY_DATABASE_IP
```

[image: kubernetes deploy]

I did a test with a Docker pointing to the same database and it works fine

`docker run --name myadmin -d -e PMA_HOST=MY_DATABASE_IP -p 8080:80 phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:5`

[image: docker run]

Comment: Hi, Do You have [`Service`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) that exposes Your deployment? Unlike in docker kubernetes needs `Service` to expose deployments and pods. Alternative solution would be to deploy phpmyadmin using a helm chart like this [one](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/phpmyadmin).

Comment: Hi, yes I have the service and ingress created. when the pod is created it is not starting the apache, I must manually start it with `service apache2 start` but I still have the problem with the environment variable PMA_HOST that is not taking from the spec in order to connect to the database